# How to use Teststack.white with multiple monitors

Tags: c#-4.0, white-framework, black-box-testing

I have a 3 monitor setup, but white says:

```
[Warn - 10:59:24 AM] 'TestStack.White.UIItems.UIItem' Window with title: MYWINDOW 
whose dimensions are: 0,0,4492,1080, is not contained completely on the desktop 
0,0,1920,1080. 
UI actions on window needing mouse would not work in area not falling under the desktop
```

Is it possible to use teststack.white on multiple monitors?
If its not available then I'd like to contribute to the white project (I think its open source) and add this functionality, but we'll see.

Thanks.

Comment: I use multiple monitor setup. Never encountered an issue. White pick up the application window from given process or by given title. Never tried to deliberately switch between apps open in different monitors though